# Is there a word for the act or technique of conveying movement in a single frame?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Is there a word for the act or technique of conveying movement in a single frame? I am wondering if there's exist such a word.

Answer (score 1):

Your image combines multiples, motion lines ('whoosh lines') and blurring. These are explained and illustrated [here](https://timpickup.wordpress.com/2009/05/28/motion-lines/), [here](https://www.traditionalanimation.com/2017/smear-speed-motion-blur-effects-in-animation/) and [here](https://www.newscientist.com/gallery/on-the-move/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would apply:
[vanimation *the smear*](https://www.vanimations.com/animation-techniques-the-smear/)

> Smear frames, animation smears...
> "Smear uses a single frame or short run of frames and depicts one quick blur."